# No leader elected while using hazelcast distributed lock via CP/RaftConsensus

Tags: hazelcast

Facing `com.hazelcast.cp.exception.NotLeaderException` in all the server nodes while using CP. I suspect no leader was elected of all the available nodes.

Hazelcast management center shows all three nodes available in CP subsystem.

> [3.12] Retrying invocation: Invocation{op=com.hazelcast.cp.internal.operation.DefaultRaftReplicateOp{serviceName='hz:core:raft', identityHash=1380085770, partitionId=7, replicaIndex=0, callId=84861, invocationTime=1567512586426 (2019-09-03 17:39:46.426), waitTimeout=-1, callTimeout=60000, groupId=CPGroupId{name='default', seed=0, commitIndex=13}, op=com.hazelcast.cp.internal.session.operation.HeartbeatSessionOp{serviceName='hz:core:raftSession', sessionId=4}}, tryCount=250, tryPauseMillis=500, invokeCount=220, callTimeoutMillis=60000, firstInvocationTimeMs=1567512490707, firstInvocationTime='2019-09-03 17:38:10.707', lastHeartbeatMillis=0, lastHeartbeatTime='1970-01-01 05:30:00.000', target=[10.244.2.33]:5701, pendingResponse={VOID}, backupsAcksExpected=0, backupsAcksReceived=0, connection=Connection[id=4, /10.244.5.89:5701->/10.244.2.33:47055, qualifier=null, endpoint=[10.244.2.33]:5701, alive=true, type=MEMBER]}, Reason: com.hazelcast.cp.exception.NotLeaderException: CPMember{uuid=2f73707c-dc93-4f2c-9767-ae76aab2d0a9, address=[10.244.2.33]:5701} is not LEADER of CPGroupId{name='default', seed=0, commitIndex=13}. Known leader is: N/A

Comment: Hi. Your question is not very clear. To understand what is really going on, please describe the issue more clearly. Also add more logs, configuration etc.

Comment: It seems this is the related issue on Hazelcast Github repo: https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/15514